# What is the difference between unique_index and unique?

Tags: go, go-gorm

What is the difference  between unique_index and unique in GORM?
I am using MySQL 8.0, I cannot find the description about the difference between unique_index & unique form manual.
From [here](http://gorm.io/docs/models.html), see specifically the `Email` and `MemberNumber` fields:

> ## Declaring Models
>
> Models are usually just normal Golang structs, basic Go types, or pointers of them. sql.Scanner and driver.Valuer interfaces are also supported.
>
> Model Example:
>
> ```
> type User struct {
>     gorm.Model
>     Name         string
>     Age          sql.NullInt64
>     Birthday     *time.Time
>     Email        string  `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
>     Role         string  `gorm:"size:255"` // set field size to 255
>     MemberNumber *string `gorm:"unique;not null"` // set member number to unique and not null
>     Num          int     `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"` // set num to auto incrementable
>     Address      string  `gorm:"index:addr"` // create index with name `addr` for address
>     IgnoreMe     int     `gorm:"-"` // ignore this field
> }
> ```

Comment: this question is belongs to mysql tag here you can read about it https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/26/sql-server-difference-between-unique-index-vs-unique-constraint/

Comment: @ManjeetThakur: I find it funny that you mention this needs a MySQL tag, then recommend an article about Microsoft SQL Server :)

Comment: @Flimzy well you are right, the reason behind the concept is same

Answer (score 15):

`unique` is a database constraint that (in this case) prevents the multiple record have the same value for `MemberNumber`. If such an insert or update is made, the operation will not succeed and return an error.

`unique_index` will create a database index that also ensures that no two values can be the same. It will do the same, but create an index.

In your case: MySQL will use a unique index behind the scenes when using a unique constraint. So when using MySQL, there is no difference when using `unique` and using `unique index`.

If you use other database management systems there might be differences.

The differences (if any) will be handled by the database management system internally. For practical purposes you can regard them as the same. The differences will be documented for each database management system.